# Trying to loop a search from Visual basic

Tags: vba, excel, while-loop, compiler-errors, basic

I am trying to perform a search for a few rows of data in excel using visual basic.

Basically, search a website for each product...doesn't much matter if it opens multiple windows or tabs or whatever...nothing needs to be done with the webpages yet either.  Here is my current attempt:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim index As Integer
    index = 1
    Dim searchme As String


    While Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(index, 1).Value <> Null        
        searchme = worsheets("Sheet1").Cells(index, 1).Value        
        searchmelink = "https://www.grainger.com/search?" & _
                    "searchBar=true&searchQuery=" & searchme  

        ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=searchmelink, NewWindow:=True

        index = index + 1        
    End While

End Sub
```

I am getting an error at `End While` for some reason.

> "Compile error:
>
> Expected: If or Select or Sub or Function or Property or Type or With
>   or Enum or end of statement"

help me please, probably very simple but I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

While is implemented like this:

```
While {test}
    {actions}
Wend
```

or more typically:

```
Do While {test}
    {actions}
Loop
```

Comment: Thank you Tim.  I supposed I asked a bit prematurely and instead did something like:

Do Until IsEmpty(....)

loop

thanks!